# How to get rid of margins

Tags: r, plot, margin, margins

I designated the width, height, and resolution of the plot, then removed the margins as in the below code, and drew a plot.

But I still have margins. I got the same plot with and without the `par` command. The uploaded image was reduced from 7000*5000 to 1400*1000 to reduce under 2MB.

[image]

```
library(scatterplot3d)

parwd = 7000
parht = 5000
parres = 1000

par(oma = c(0,0,0,0), mar = c(0,0,0,0))

jpeg(filename="CC_1_fo.jpg", width = parwd, height = parht, res = parres)
scatterplot3d(1:10, 1:10, 1:10,
              cex.symbol = 0.2,
              xlab = expression(T[1]),
              ylab = expression(T[2]),
              zlab = expression(tau))
dev.off()
```

How can I really remove the margins?

Comment: Could you add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)?

Comment: @ProcrastinatusMaximus I don't understand why you ask reproducible example because the data don't matter in this question. Anyway I edited the question

Comment: I asked for data, because that makes it a lot easier for other people to reproduce your problem and thus makes it easier to help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess 3D plotting is a bit funky and some of the `par` arguments don't work as expected. Specifically, if you want to set margins with `mar` you have to use the actual `mar` argument *in* `scatterplot3d`.

This is stated in the notes of the help (`?scatterplot3d`):

> Some graphical parameters should only be set as arguments in
>   `scatterplot3d` but not in a previous `par()` call. One of these is
>   `mar` (...)

Using:

```
scatterplot3d(1:10, 1:10, 1:10,
              cex.symbol = 0.2,
              xlab = expression(T[1]),
              ylab = expression(T[2]),
              zlab = expression(tau),
              mar = c(0,0,0,0))
```

will result in a plot without margins:

[image]

Setting the margins to zero will cut off your tick-labels though.

Comment: `mar = c(2.7, 2.7, 0, 2)` is a good default that reduces the margins without cutting away labels (with c(bottom, left, top, right))